# Zend Framework + Smarty for a high traffic website

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

I'm considering integrating smarty with Zend Framework for a large project. The goals I want to achieve are: increase code readability and speed up development. Zend is quite heavy on it's own plus I also use PropelORM which adds to the weight. I'm not super concerned about PHP performance as there is Alternative PHP Cache which will cache the source code however I still prefer to have a good think before adding another big library to the project.

Do you have any experience with smarty under high traffic? Are there any issues I should be aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use Smarty?  What is it going to add for you?  Does it have something to do with the way you want to divide work between designers and developers?  Unless you have a really good reason why bother?  PHP is already a web scripting language.  Personally can't stand Smarty.

Comment: I answered WHY question at the beginning of my question.

Comment: I've found it does neither of those things.  Just use short tags and write good reusable view helpers.

Comment: 100% agree with the View helpers.

Comment: It will be not so easy to call view helpers in smarty template. You will need to 'invent a bicycle'.

Comment: Word, I got the code if you need it.  Fun checking if .tpl or .phtml, global $smarty, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Zend and Smarty on high traffic project ( about 40000 visits/day ) without any problems. Smarty integration is also very easy. Templates are compiled to the PHP code so don't worry about it.

Just be carefull with helpers, one stiff helper can send your server down. But that's not the Smarty issue...

Comment: I agree Smarty is brilliant. Even under high traffic. If you're using Cache, even better for HTML files. Aside from that I don't think the engine takes much consumption. A good Zend Server will eat something smooth and small like Smarty. That, with a cache.. DNS.. load balancing.. clustering.. Rapid

Comment: I guess that is the thing. Disregarding what are you using for high traffic you have to cache everything anyway.